# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 - Image

Tags: angular, image

I discover angular and I have some problems when loading images. 
I retrieve links to images from an API and assign the recovered link to the source of my image.
However, some images do not load and I get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
```

I also tried it with Chrome and Edge but the problem persists.
In the Chrome console, I can see the links that failed to be loaded. When I click on the link, I still access the image.
What is amazing is that once I click on the link and reload the page, the image loads onto my page.

Here's some code:

**Component that retrieve data:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-idole-list',
  templateUrl: './idole-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./idole-list.component.css']
})
export class IdoleListComponent implements OnInit {
  idols;
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) {
    this.idols = myService.getData();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**HTML of my Component:**

```
<div class="clr-row">
    <div class="clr-col-4" *ngFor="let idol of idols | async">
        <div class="card" >
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">{{ idol.name }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-img">
                <img [src]="idol.imgUrl">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

In Firefox, here is the response from a GET request of one of the images :

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://ankama.akamaized.net/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/200/178102.png" on this server.

Reference #18.47327b68.1563645916.138751e4
```

I don't know why I get a forbidden access on the half on the images

Comment: can you try same in chrome browser, and share result, i don't find any issue browsing it directly on chrome browser, so CORS issue is not an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the issue attached below, so this resource can be available only if request is coming from "https://www.dofus.com" when its a cross-origin, i.e your code is running on different host and asking a resource from "https://s.ankama.com"

else, it will browse perfectly fine, since origin will not change.

[image]

Now, to fix this either set

```
access-control-allow-origin : *
```

or to your domain on the server, then it will work; note you cannot set multiple domains comma separated to allow access.

If this server is not in your control, then as per the browser behavior it will not allow to load that resource if its a cross-origin request, read [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: When I use Postman I can perfectly retrieve all the image I want. But when I fetch them with angular it doesn't work for the majority except 4-5 images.
So what do I need to do to get these images ?

Comment: CORS is a property of browser only which helps us to prevent cyber crimes, and thus with Postman it works fine, i can explain it in a great detail but restricted to max-chars, you can refer [same-origin-policy](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9) which will help you clarify your question more

Comment: Ok so there is no way to  bypass it ? I search for bypass on the internet but the response send by the proxy is in a weird format

Comment: now, since the resource has only allowed access to "https://www.dofus.com", you can either direct your request to this server and fetch or, since this issue is only with cross-origin-policy of browser, you can direct your request to your server (nodejs) or reverse proxy which will eventually help you serve this resource

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `status of 403`,so this status occurs due to **authorization**.

So,try to get this image with some header or whatever needed

Comment: What do you mean by getting the image with "header" ?

Comment: for  example, authorization bearer,please examine [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization),and could you share your image url?

Comment: this is one of the image that did not load: https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/200/178073.png

Comment: There is no problem.I can show image. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdauui), Maybe another image in data has a problem.

Comment: I know it works when I make an HTTP GET request to get it. But there are like 20 images out of 50 that are not loading. When you click on the link above it works but it is when I retrieve many data that it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img src="{{idol.imgUrl}}">`

In my experience, this way of doing it works more often for some reason.

Comment: I just tested it and some of the images still not load in, and I get the same error